# MYSQL - how to average returned votes from inner joined table results

Tags: mysql, inner-join, average

I'm very much a beginner, please bear with me.

I'm trying to get the ID number from one table to point to the same number in another table, which holds a name value (ie rating.id 1 = names.id 1 and names.name "bread"), which I seem to have managed. Then I want to display the average rating next to the name, ie take all rating.rate values (range from 1-5) and average the rating, and display it next to the product, then order desc. such as :

```
name-------average rating

Coffee-----4.3

Bread------3.2

Cheese-----2.9

etc
```

So far it gives me all the product names, but shows the product name as many times as it has ratings, then ranks desc. Not much use. This is what I have :

```
SELECT rating.rate, names.name FROM rating INNER JOIN names ON rating.id = names.id ORDER BY rating.rate DESC LIMIT 0, 25 GROUP BY names.name
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example does not appear to be using the AVG function at all?  How about the below?

```
SELECT AVG(rating.rate) as avg_rating, names.name 
  FROM rating 
  JOIN names 
    ON rating.id = names.id
GROUP BY names.name
ORDER BY avg_rating DESC
LIMIT 0, 25
```

This will average out the ratings per name because of the GROUP BY.  The result of the AVG is put in to avg_rating and used in the ORDER BY.

Comment: This worked right away, thank you ever so much!
I had tried using AVG, I didn't post my attempt because it was clearly not how to do it and didn't want to confuse with a wall of my silly thoughts on the matter.